# Add a 3rd party framework to OS X Xcode 4 project

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

I want to add Oomph's [MacMapKit](https://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit) as a framework to my Xcode (v4.3.2) project. I've already added a couple of standard Apple frameworks to my project (which was a breeze) but this is new to me and offers a rather intimidating array of settings and options.

Before I start clicking around in my project/build settings, I would like to ask:

- (1) Is the MacMapKit framework in its current state technically speaking
  "a framework"? From [this post](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/04/cocoa-tutorial-creating-your-very-own-framework/) I gather that a Cocoa framework
  requires some special preparation with Xcode and as such MacMapKit
  would possibly not qualify.
- (2) What would be the best way to add MacMapKit (source and resource files) in its current state to
  my own project? I've read about various approaches which all seem to
  assume you have an actual framework, which I'm not sure MacMapKit
  qualifies for (see question 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MacMapKit has several targets. One of the targets is the MapKit Framework.
You need to build this target first in order to use it like a common framework.

So just select the "MapKitFramework" target from the schemes list and build.